# Page not found for reputation league of private beta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, 500-server-error, reputation-page

In the atheism private beta, if I go to the reputation league page [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/74/week/atheism) it gives me a Page not found page.

Answer (score 4):

How is this a bug?

- it's in private beta, emphasis on *private*
- even if it wasn't, there is no existing data to calculate any league data from
- it is technically possible for sites to never make it out of private beta and die

Comment: On the 3rd point — how? I don't see any good reason that a site can pass the commitment phase without closing but killed within 7 days of private beta.

Comment: @kenny I didn't say it was *likely* but it is possible. There is some discussion that http://ai.stackexchange.com is currently so very bad that it should have been killed in private beta.

Comment: I'm part of the private beta, so it ought to be appearing for me or saying "No data yet".